# Dynamic SELECT statement, generate columns based on present and future values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor, pivot-table

Currently building a `SELECT` statement in SQL Server 2008 but would like to make this `SELECT` statement dynamic, so the columns can be defined based on values in a table. I heard about pivot table and cursors, but seems kind of hard to understand at my current level, here is the code;

```
DECLARE @date DATE = null

IF @date is null
set @ date = GETDATE() as DATE

SELECT
    Name,
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
    value4
FROM ref_Table a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
       PK_ID ID,
       sum(case when FK_ContainerType_ID = 1 then 1 else null) Box,
       sum(case when FK_ContainerType_ID = 2 then 1 else null) Pallet,
       sum(case when FK_ContainerType_ID = 3 then 1 else null) Bag,
       sum(case when FK_ContainerType_ID = 4 then 1 else null) Drum
    from 
       Packages  
    WHERE 
       @date between PackageStart AND PackageEnd
    group by PK_ID ) b on a.Name = b.ID
where 
    Group = 0
```

The following works great for me , but PK_Type_ID and the name of the column(PackageNameX,..) are hard coded, I need to be dynamic and it can build itself based on present or futures values in the `Package` table.

Any help or guidance on the right direction would be greatly appreciated...,

As requested

`ref_Table`  (PK_ID, Name)

```
1, John
2, Mary
3, Albert
4, Jane
```

`Packages` (PK_ID, FK_ref_Table_ID, FK_ContainerType_ID, PackageStartDate, PackageEndDate)

```
1 , 1, 4, 1JAN2014, 30JAN2014
2 , 2, 3, 1JAN2014, 30JAN2014
3 , 3, 2, 1JAN2014, 30JAN2014
4 , 4, 1, 1JAN2014, 30JAN2014
```

`ContainerType` (PK_ID, Type)

```
1, Box
2, Pallet
3, Bag
4, Drum
```

and the result should look like this;

```
Name     Box     Pallet    Bag    Drum
---------------------------------------
John                                1
Mary                        1
Albert              1
Jane       1
```

The following code like I said works great, the issue is the `Container` table is going to grow and I need to replicated the same report without hard coding the columns.

Comment: Can you please provide a schema with some sample data and expected output example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to build is called a dynamic pivot.  There are plenty of good references on Stack if you search out that term.

Here is a solution to your scenario:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ref_Table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##ref_Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Packages') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Packages
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ContainerType') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##ContainerType

SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE ##ref_Table (PK_ID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE ##Packages (PK_ID INT, FK_ref_Table_ID INT, FK_ContainerType_ID INT, PackageStartDate DATE, PackageEndDate DATE)
CREATE TABLE ##ContainerType (PK_ID INT, [Type] NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO ##ref_Table (PK_ID,NAME)
SELECT 1,'John' UNION
SELECT 2,'Mary' UNION
SELECT 3,'Albert' UNION
SELECT 4,'Jane'

INSERT INTO ##Packages (PK_ID, FK_ref_Table_ID, FK_ContainerType_ID, PackageStartDate, PackageEndDate)
SELECT 1,1,4,'2014-01-01','2014-01-30' UNION
SELECT 2,2,3,'2014-01-01','2014-01-30' UNION
SELECT 3,3,2,'2014-01-01','2014-01-30' UNION
SELECT 4,4,1,'2014-01-01','2014-01-30' 

INSERT INTO ##ContainerType (PK_ID, [Type])
SELECT 1,'Box' UNION
SELECT 2,'Pallet' UNION
SELECT 3,'Bag' UNION
SELECT 4,'Drum' 

DECLARE @DATE DATE, @PARAMDEF NVARCHAR(MAX), @COLS NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DATE = '2014-01-15'

SET @COLS = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + QUOTENAME(T.[Type])
            FROM ##ContainerType T
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @SQL = 'SELECT [Name], ' + @COLS + ' 
            FROM (SELECT [Name], [Type], 1 AS Value
                  FROM ##ref_Table R
                  JOIN ##Packages P ON R.PK_ID = P.FK_ref_Table_ID
                  JOIN ##ContainerType T ON P.FK_ContainerType_ID = T.PK_ID
                  WHERE @DATE BETWEEN P.PackageStartDate AND P.PackageEndDate) X
            PIVOT (COUNT(Value) FOR [Type] IN (' + @COLS + ')) P
            '
PRINT @COLS
PRINT @SQL
SET @PARAMDEF = '@DATE DATE'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMDEF, @DATE=@DATE
```

Output:

```
Name    Bag     Box     Drum    Pallet
Albert  0       0       0       1
Jane    0       1       0       0
John    0       0       1       0
Mary    1       0       0       0
```

Comment: NB: if you'd like to see `NULL` instead of 0 for absent data, change `COUNT(Value)` to `SUM(Value)` within the dynamic SQL string.

Answer (score -1):

**Static Query:**

```
SELECT [Name],[Box],[Pallet],[Bag],[Drum] FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  rf.Name,cnt.[Type], pk.PK_ID AS PKID, rf.PK_ID AS RFID
        FROM ref_Table rf INNER JOIN Packages pk ON rf.PK_ID = pk.FK_ref_Table_ID
        INNER JOIN ContanerType cnt ON cnt.PK_ID = pk.FK_ContainerType_ID
     ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
           COUNT(PKID )
           FOR [Type]
           IN ( [Box],[Pallet],[Bag],[Drum])
    ) AS PivotTable
) AS Main
ORDER BY RFID
```

**Dynamic Query:**

```
DECLARE @columnList nvarchar (MAX)
DECLARE @pivotsql nvarchar (MAX)

SELECT @columnList =   STUFF(
             (
             SELECT ',' + '[' + [Type] + ']'
           FROM ContanerType
           FOR XML PATH( '')
           )
        ,1, 1,'' )


SET @pivotsql =
N'SELECT [Name],' + @columnList + ' FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  rf.Name,cnt.[Type], pk.PK_ID AS PKID, rf.PK_ID AS RFID
        FROM ref_Table rf INNER JOIN Packages pk ON rf.PK_ID = pk.FK_ref_Table_ID
        INNER JOIN ContanerType cnt ON cnt.PK_ID = pk.FK_ContainerType_ID
     ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
           COUNT(PKID )
           FOR [Type]
           IN ( ' + @columnList + ')
    ) AS PivotTable
) AS Main
ORDER BY RFID;'

EXEC sp_executesql @pivotsql
```

Following my tutorial below will help you to understand the PIVOT functionality:

We write sql queries in order to get different result sets like full, partial, calculated, grouped, sorted etc from the database tables. However sometimes we have requirements that we have to rotate our tables. Sounds confusing?

Let's keep it simple and consider the following two screen grabs.

**SQL Table:**
[image]

**Expected Results:**
[image]

Wow, that's look like a lot of work! That is a combination of tricky sql, temporary tables, loops, aggregation......, blah blah blah

Don't worry let's keep it simple, stupid(**KISS**).

MS SQL Server 2005 and above has a function called PIVOT. It s very simple to use and powerful. With the help of this function we will be able to rotate sql tables and result sets.

**Simple steps to make it happen:**

1. Identify all the columns those will be part of the desired result set.
2. Find the column on which we will apply aggregation(sum,ave,max,min etc)
3. Identify the column which values will be the column header.
4. Specify the column values mentioned in **step3** with comma separated and surrounded by square brackets.

So, if we now follow above four steps and extract information from the above sales table, it will be as below:

1. Year, Month, SalesAmount
2. SalesAmount
3. Month
4. [Jan],[Feb] ,[Mar] .... etc

We are nearly there if all the above steps made sense to you so far.

Now we have all the information we need. All we have to do now is to fill the below template with required information.
**Template:**
[image]
Our SQL query should look like below:

SELECT *

```
FROM
(
    SELECT SalesYear, SalesMonth,Amount
    FROM Sales
 ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
       SUM(Amount )
       FOR SalesMonth
       IN ( [Jan],[Feb] ,[Mar],
            [Apr],[May],[Jun] ,[Jul],
            [Aug],[Sep] ,[Oct],[Nov] ,[Dec])
) AS PivotTable;
```

In the above query we have hard coded the column names. Well it's not fun when you have to specify a number of columns.

However, there is a work arround as follows:

```
DECLARE @columnList nvarchar (MAX)
DECLARE @pivotsql nvarchar (MAX)

SELECT @columnList =   STUFF(
             (
               SELECT ',' + '[' + SalesMonth + ']'
               FROM Sales
               GROUP BY SalesMonth
               FOR XML PATH( '')
           )
        ,1, 1,'' )

SET @pivotsql =
       N'SELECT *
      FROM
      (
            SELECT SalesYear, SalesMonth,Amount
            FROM Sales
       ) AS SourceTable
      PIVOT
      (
           SUM(Amount )
           FOR SalesMonth
           IN ( ' + @columnList +' )
      ) AS PivotTable;'

EXEC sp_executesql @pivotsql
```

Hopefully this tutorial will be a help to someone somewhere.
Enjoy coding.