# How to use pivot query dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have here a query: (this was modified. thank you SO for the help) and I'm using mssql 2008

```
SELECT 'Risk','ADAB','Bahrain','Kuwait','Masirah','Qatar' <-- fixed
UNION ALL
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,risk)
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[ADAB]) as ADAB <-- fixed
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Bahrain]) as Bahrain <-- fixed
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Kuwait]) as Kuwait <-- fixed
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Masirah]) as Masirah <-- fixed
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Qatar]) as Qatar <-- fixed

from (select risk, piv_site = risk, site
        from qcvqciffull
        where (1=1) AND Risk is not null) as ps
pivot (count(piv_site)
        for site in ([ADAB], [Bahrain], [Kuwait], [Masirah], [Qatar])) as pvt <-- fixed
```

I have here a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9906/3). Is it possible to turn those fields who have "fixed" text beside it and turn them dynamically? Say, I have a new record coming in, `USA` for instance. Is there a way for it?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely possible. Just search dynamic pivot here on SO. Lots of great samples.

Comment: Hello Mate, Thanks. Think you can provide some links? I'm doing my best trying some examples I can find.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174223/dynamic-select-statement-generate-columns-based-on-present-and-future-values/24175389#24175389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current scenerio, you have to add whatever text will add other than this.

Or

you can go for dynamic pivot which automatically find and create column, where you have to create dynamic query and then execute.

Refer this :- [Dynamic Pivot](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
       + QUOTENAME(Course)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM #CourseSales) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
  N'SELECT Year, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #Tablename
    PIVOT(SUM(Earning)
          FOR Course IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```