# how to make the field value to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below.

```
+----------+
| Tools    |
+----------+
| Pencil   |
| Eraser   |
| Notebook |
| Pencil   |
| Notebook |
| Notebook |
+----------+
```

Can I transform it to something like this?

```
+---------+----------+---------+
| No name | No name  | No Name | <-- column header
+---------+----------+---------+ 
| Pencil  | Notebook | Eraser  | <-- values
+---------+----------+---------+
```

Tried `pivot` query but I don't think I got it right. Those tools may are not fixed. I mean, maybe they would add another tools for it.
Any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: What're the table attributes ?

Comment: Those could be varchar

Comment: You just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276355/how-to-use-pivot-query-dynamically -- both answers are dynamic pivots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174223/dynamic-select-statement-generate-columns-based-on-present-and-future-values/24175389#24175389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table(tools varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('Pencil'),('Eraser'),('Notebook'),('Pencil'),('Notebook'),('Notebook')

select * from @t

SELECT *
FROM ( 
    select 
    tools
    from @t 
    group by tools
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(tools)
  FOR tools IN(Pencil, Eraser, Notebook)
) AS p;
```

Comment: Why the `MAX` function?

Comment: you have to use any aggregate function in pivot, in here max is used for temporary to come out result. No use of this, but it is compulsory that why we use.

Comment: It is working as a sorting in alphabet. simply check - select MAX(tools)  from @t